# How to convert yyyymmdd to Julian date in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convent `yyyymmdd` to Julian date.

> Ex 20091225 to get 2455190.5

( I got this value from a Julian converter calculator)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
I am trying to do this in MS sql server 2012.

I tried this:

```
select ((cast (
    cast(datepart(year, '2009-12-25') as varchar) +
    cast (datepart(month, '2009-12-25') as varchar) +
    cast (datepart(day, '2009-12-25') as varchar) as int)) - 2451550.1)

return : 17639674.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ((cast (
    cast(datepart(year, '2009-12-25') as varchar) +
    cast (datepart(month, '2009-12-25') as varchar) +
    cast (datepart(day, '2009-12-25') as varchar) as int)) - 2400000.5)
```

Julian number is : 2400000.5

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day